# How can I plot points on a 1d number line in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I'd like to create a 1-dimensional chart in Google Sheets. The chart effectively plots values on a number line like so:

```
              A                   B    C     D           E
|-------------O-------------------O----O-----O-----------O----------|
0                                                                  100
```

I've tried all kinds of scatter plot configurations but I can't get the right result.

Ideally I'd like to have:

- A 1D chart, vertical or horizontal is fine
- The chart plots points say from 0 to 100, the points should be labelled

Comment: Just to create a number line is easy. But is that what you want? Or do you want the points to automatically be plotted and labelled based on a set of data? Please post a sample spreadsheet with some sample data.

Comment: Yes, I'd like points to be plotted on the line based on a set of data.

Comment: @DavidWang I've created a sheet with data to match (roughly) the ascii chart I have in the question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yNoWyMocbEZVVZqGwAokDQbbPZt0MxIkJ0GajVeKTOs/edit#gid=0

Comment: @joelittlejohn Did you ever resolve this question?